# Change mobile menu color from red to another color

Tags: css, mobile

Hello I am trying to build a website and I am going crazy with mobile menu colors. I was able to change mobile menu color from red to blue. But when I hover from one page to another, previous menu stays as red.

```css
/*change color on mobile media query*/
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
    .main-navigation .blaskan-main-menu > ul, .main-navigation .blaskan-main-menu > div {
    background: #000000;
    }
    #primary-menu > li > a,.main-navigation ul ul li a {
    color: #1966D3;
    }
}

@media screen and ( max-width: 1280px ) {
    .main-navigation li a:hover, .main-navigation li a:focus, .main-navigation li a:active {
    color: #1966D3;
    }
}
```

This is the code that I put. So I want all submenu items to be blue including arrow and do not change their color. Could you help me please? www.yalniziyigezdim.net is my website.

Comment: Can you include the result of your developer tools - it's quite possible that something is overriding your settings.  Also, let us know if you're using a custom theme or a child theme.  As much detail as is possible.

Comment: Hello. I am using elementor .Thanks a lot